# Initializing elements of a 2D array using std::array. c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using `std::array<array<float, 4,3> = . . .` to in
I'm having trouble understand how to format the following code so I don't get the following error:

```
g++ array2d_colors.cpp -o array2dcolors.o
array2d_colors.cpp: In function ‘void arrayStart()’:
array2d_colors.cpp:36:7: error: too many initializers for 
‘std::array<std::array<float, 4ul>, 3ul>’        };
       ^


using namespace;
  array<array<float,4>,3> color = {
      {  0.0 , 0.1686 , 0.2117 },
      {   0.0274 , 0.2117 , 0.2588},
      {   0.3450 , 0.4313 , 0.4588},
      {   0.3960 , 0.4823, 0.5137}
      };
```

This  code worked in another study:

```
using namespace;
array<array<float, 2>, 2> a1 = {{{5,6},{7,8}}};
```

That is a lot of "{'s" . What if a want to create a 16x3?
I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing

```
 array<array<float,4>,3> color
```

you're saying that the inner array has 4 elements and the outer one has 3. So it becomes a 4*3 matrix while you're defining a 3*4 matrix.

Try doing :

```
array<array<float,3>,4> color = {{
  {  0.0 , 0.1686 , 0.2117 },
  {   0.0274 , 0.2117 , 0.2588},
  {   0.3450 , 0.4313 , 0.4588},
  {   0.3960 , 0.4823, 0.5137}
  }};
```

and remember to add {{ - two braces before defining the array of inner arrays and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

You have the initializer arrays transposed to a `4 x 3` array. Hence, it does not match the declaration of `color`.

You can use:

```
array<array<float, 3>, 4> color = 
   {
      {  0.0 , 0.1686 , 0.2117 },     // 1st of four of the outer array
      {  0.0274 , 0.2117 , 0.2588},
      {  0.3450 , 0.4313 , 0.4588},
      {  0.3960 , 0.4823, 0.5137}    // 4th of four of the outer array
   };
```

If you need to have a `3 x 4` array, you have to change the initializer array.

Ex:

```
array<array<float, 4>, 3> color = 
   {
      {  0.0 , 0.1686 , 0.2117, 1 },     // 1st of three of the outer array
      {  0.0274 , 0.2117 , 0.2588, 2},
      {  0.3960 , 0.4823, 0.5137, 3}    // 3rd of three of the outer array
   };
```

Comment: Wow!  That was simple.  Thanks for all the posts and help!

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1**: Dimensions are swtitched

```
array<array<float,3>,4> color = {
//                 ^  ^
```

**Issue 2**: Explicitly mention the type of array in initializer. Compiler can't deduce it.

```
  array<float,3>{   0.0 , 0.1686 , 0.2117 },
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  {   0.0274 , 0.2117 , 0.2588},
  {   0.3450 , 0.4313 , 0.4588},
  {   0.3960 , 0.4823, 0.5137}
```